# ¿Qué pasa si pierdo la conexión a la máquina?

Tags: sql

Qué pasaría si estoy haciendo SQL y de repente pierdo la conexión a la máquina, perdería todo, ¿verdad? Si es así, ¿qué tengo que añadir en el script principal para que no ocurra?

Answer (score 2):

Te refieres a una consulta "Select" o un update o delete?
En el caso de un select en principio recuperarías las filas mientras tengas conexión , pero en el caso de hacer un delete o update en principio como lanzarías la orden y se ejecutaría en el servidor...hablamos de una operación en muchos casos de milisegundos.

Comment: Efectivamente, que no te devuelva un resultado de la consulta no significa que la operación no se haya realizado correctamente sobre la bd. Como dice el compañero @ilernet la operación se produce en una franja de tiempo tan pequeña que o llega la consulta o no llega pero a medias no se puede quedar.